# Restriction of relative sheaf on a section

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

suppose $X\rightarrow Y$ is a projective bundle or rank $r$.
Let $S$ be a section of this bundle.
What is the restriction of the relative tangent bundle $T_{X/Y}$ on the section $S$ ? Is it free ?

Comment: It would be useful to know some more on $Y$. Is it a smooth scheme?

Comment: yes $Y$ is a smooth variety.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter whether $Y$ is smooth actually... Let's say it's noetherian for safety.

Let $\pi: X=\mathbb P(\mathscr E)\to Y$ where $\mathscr E$ is a rank $r+1$ locally free sheaf on $Y$ and let $\mathscr O_{\mathbb P(\mathscr E)}(1)$ be the associated relative very ample line bundle. Then one has the natural short exact sequence:

$$
0 \to \Omega_{X/Y} \to \pi^*\mathscr E\otimes \mathscr O_{\mathbb P(\mathscr E)}(-1) \to \mathscr O_{\mathbb P(\mathscr E)} \to 0
$$

Now let $\sigma: Y\to X$ be a section. Recall that sections of projective bundles are in one-to-one correspondence with surjections to line bundles: $\mathscr E\to \mathscr L$. Restricting the above short exact sequence to the section is the same as pulling it back to $Y$ via $\sigma$, so we get that the restricted sequence is

$$
0 \to \Omega_{X/Y}|_{\sigma(Y)} \to \mathscr E\otimes \sigma^*\mathscr O_{\mathbb P(\mathscr E)}(-1) \to \mathscr O_{Y} \to 0
$$

By the above correspondence between sections and surjective maps $\sigma^*\mathscr O_{\mathbb P(\mathscr E)}(1)\simeq \mathscr L$ and the map on the right hand side of the above sequence corresponds to the surjective map $\mathscr E\to \mathscr L$.

So we get that we may interpret the above sequence the following way:

$$
0 \to \Omega_{X/Y}|_{\sigma(Y)} \to \mathscr E\otimes \mathscr L^{-1} \to \mathscr O_{Y} \to 0
$$

so the restriction $T_{X/Y}|_{\sigma(Y)}$ is the cokernel of the map 
$\mathscr O_Y\to \mathscr Hom_Y(\mathscr E, \mathscr L)$ that maps $1\in \mathscr O_Y$ to the surjective map corresponding to the section $\sigma$. This may or may not be free depending on the bundle and the section.

Comment: thanks for the explanation..actually iam looking at a grassmannian bundle $G(E)\rightarrow X$. Iam looking for a section $s$ (defined outside a codimension two subset) so that $T_{G(E)/X}$ restricted to $s$ is free. Does this seem possible.

Comment: @john: Yes, that is also true.  Sandor's solution extends quite easily to that setting.  The Euler sequence is replaced by $$0\to \Omega_{X/Y} \to \pi^*\mathcal{E}\otimes S \to \textit{Hom}(S,S) \to 0,$$ where $S$ is the universal subbundle on your Grassmannian (i.e., the dual $S^\vee$ is the universal quotient bundle).  For projective space, $S$ is $\mathcal{O}(-1)$.

Comment: for the grassmannian bundle $G(E)\rightarrow X$, does a section (outside a codim two subset) correspond to a surjection $E\rightarrow L$ , where $L$ is a line bundle on $X$?

Comment: @john: "... does a section correspond to a surjection $E\to L$ where $L$ is a line bundle on $X$?"  No, not typically.  The universal property of the Grassmannian is that there exists a universal surjection $\pi^*\mathcal{E}\to S^\vee$ where $S^\vee$ is a locally free sheaf of the specified rank, say $r$.  If $r$ equals $1$, then $S^\vee$ is an invertible sheaf, i.e., line bundle.  But in that case, the Grassmannian is actually a projective bundle.  So for Grassmannians that are not projective bundles, $S^\vee$ is not an invertible sheaf.